# Find all blobs with prepend in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core

We use Azure's `.NET Core` SDK for blob storage to get and update static blobs, and I want to be able to find all blobs in a specific directory prepended with a certain string of characters.

I can find individual items using something like:

```
string fileName = "c999iconFile.png";

var blob = _myDirectory.GetBlobReference(fileName);
```

But I can't seem to be able to find a way to find all `blobs` prepended with something like `c999`.

We're looking to find a list of blobs that match a certain prepend and then make a mass delete on them.

The brute force solution is to iterate through one-by-one and do it but that seems wasteful.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as *files* and *directories* in a blob storage. Blobs are just named bytes (that may contains `/` characters). However, you can see directory trees on azure portal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I can't seem to be able to find a way to find all blobs prepended
>   with something like c999.

You can perform a `prefix` based search where the storage service returns you a list of blobs names of which starts with a certain prefix ("c999" in your case).

```
var blobs = blobContainerClient.GetBlobs(traits = Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobTraits.None, states = Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobStates.None, string prefix = "c999");
```

Reference: [`BlobContainerClient.GetBlobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.getblobs?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobContainerClient_GetBlobs_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobTraits_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobStates_System_String_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

Above code is for SDK v12. If you're using an older version of the library, here's the code that you would use:

```
var blobs = blobContainer.ListBlobs(prefix = "c999", bool useFlatBlobListing = true);
```

Reference: [`CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs?view=azure-dotnet-legacy)

Comment: I don't seem to have the method `GetBlobs` on my client, the storage account object or any of the referenced containers... This seems to be from the `.NET Framework` SDK, not the `.NET Core` SDK.

Comment: What version of SDK you're using? This is from the latest version (according to the documentation).

Comment: `WindowsAzure.Storage` version `9.3.3` which is a different namespace to `Azure.Storage`. I've ran into this before working with `Service Buses` their docs only seem to list `Framework` APIs and bury the `.NET Core` APIs elsewhere. The ref you've given is definitely `Framework`, but thank you.

Comment: Here's the link to the source code: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/src/BlobContainerClient.cs#L1671

Comment: Updated my answer and included code for older version of the SDK.

Comment: Seems there are multiple SDKs released for this... `WindowsAzure.Storage` is completely separate to `Azure.Storage`, each with their own `Nuget` listings etc. Looks like I'll have to update the SDK to `Azure.Storage` to achieve this. After version 9.4 this happened, so your answer is correct and I've simply got an old version of the SDK. Thanks!